# Manga about a boy with the power to grow plants

Tags: story-identification, magic, manga, parallel-universe, plants

The story is about a boy with magical powers related to growing and reviving plants. One day, another boy appears in his home. The stranger is from another world, where there are no plants because there is not enough water (there's only sand in that world).

After meeting him, the stranger notices the protagonist looks exactly like the prince from his own world, who nobody likes, because he is a bad person. The protagonist and the stranger start living together, while the stranger learns about life on Earth (everything is different from his world).

Then, another guy arrives at the protagonist's house. He is from the same world where everywhere is a desert. Moreover, since the appearance of the two strangers, the protagonist's powers increase, and he is able to give new life to dead plants and trees.

If someone knows the title of this manga, please tell me!

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. If anyone correctly identifies this, you can mark their answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is ***[Silver Diamond](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/silver-diamond)***.

From Anime-Planet:

> Rakan is the only surviving member of his family, so he lives alone with only a flourishing garden to keep him company. **One day, a mysterious man falls into Rakan's garden and tries to kill him, but instead of getting angry Rakan feeds the man, gives him hot food, and offers him a place to stay. As more people mysteriously follow suit Rakan discovers that he looks just like the evil prince of a different world - a man who is exiling unwanted people out of his territory.** With the help of this band of misfits - a monster, a man who should have been a woman, a snake that can turn into a sword and a number child - **Rakan sets forth to set things right and bring green back to the desert of his new friends' world.**

From [Screen Rant](https://screenrant.com/highest-rated-isekai-manga-myanimelist/):

> While peacefully tending to his garden, Rakan Sawa is threatened by a man named Chigusa who mysteriously crash lands into his garden. **Upon learning Rakan is a "sanome," those who can cultivate and manipulate plant life, Chigusa asks Rakan to travel to his world and save it from the plant-killing creatures known as "ayame."**